# How to disable right click in WebBrowser when we're using Flash ! (Delphi)

Tags: flash, delphi, browser, right-click

How can i disable the menu of flash player when I'm navigating a flash file with WebBrowser ?

Answer (score 4):

All messages that are sent to the WebBrowser, pass through your Delphi application as well, so by using a TApplicationEvents component and checking for the right-click event in the OnMessage event on the Handle of WebBrowser, or any of it's child handles (use [IsChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633524%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) and set Handled, you should be able to block it.

The code could look like this

```
procedure TMyForm.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (Msg.message=WM_RBUTTONDOWN) and IsChild(WebBrowser1.Handle,Msg.hwnd) then
   begin
    PopupMenu1.Popup(Msg.pt.X,Msg.pt.Y);
    Handled:=true;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for response , may you give me an example ?

Answer (score 1):

Heres another way.

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseActivate(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y, HitTest: Integer;
  var MouseActivate: TMouseActivate);
begin
  if Button=mbRight then
  begin
    if (x >= WebBrowser1.Left) and
       (x <= WebBrowser1.Left + WebBrowser1.Width ) and
       (y >= WebBrowser1.Top) and
       (y <= WebBrowser1.Top + WebBrowser1.Height ) then
      MouseActivate := maNoActivateAndEat;
  end;
end;
```